# Equivalents in C Sharp of Java's NavigableMap.floorEntry, ceilingEntry

Tags: java, c#, data-structures

I have used the `NavigableMap` interface many a time in Java, it's handy.

Specifically, I like to use its `floorEntry` and `ceilingEntry` methods, which get you the next lowest or highest map entry, respectively.

I am trying to find the equivalents of these in C# but I am coming up short. Below is an example of what I am trying to get.

I've looked at C# `SortedDictionary` and extension methods, and, while it seems like it'd be in the ballpark, I haven't found exactly what I'm looking for.

Thanks!
L

```
package com.lewis.needsanavigablemapincsharp;

import java.util.NavigableMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        NavigableMap<Float, String> neededMap = new TreeMap<Float, String>();

        neededMap.put(1.0f, "first!");
        neededMap.put(3.0f, "second!");

        System.out.println("see how useful this is? (looking up indices that aren't in my map)");
        System.out.println(neededMap.floorEntry(2.0f));
        System.out.println(neededMap.ceilingEntry(2.0f));

    }
}
```

the output is:

> see how useful this is? (looking up indices that aren't in my map)
>   1.0=first!
>   3.0=second!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution, unfortunately, requires you to write custom extensions. So, I have already done it, and uploaded it as a gist: [SortedDictionaryExtensions.cs](https://gist.github.com/R2D221/f0363e0ee7123c4d7693).

It makes use of the `List<T>.BinarySearch` method by converting the dictionary's key collection to a list. Then, with help to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3486820/1858296), we determine if the key exists, and if not, we get the floor and ceiling values as a bitwise complement, and then choose which one we need for the method.

Please note I haven't tested the efficiency of this algorithm, but as a first glance it seems good enough.

You can test it like this:

```
SortedDictionary<float, string> neededMap = new SortedDictionary<float, string>();

neededMap.Add(1.0f, "first!");
neededMap.Add(3.0f, "second!");

Console.WriteLine("see how useful this is? (looking up indices that aren't in my map)");
Console.WriteLine(neededMap.FloorEntry(2.0f));
Console.WriteLine(neededMap.CeilingEntry(2.0f));
```

Comment: I didn't post the whole code here because it's long, but if it's really needed, I can insert it.

Comment: Nice!  I ended up implementing a similar custom solution before seeing this response but it was a bit lazier (using linq etc ).  Yours is nicer :)

Comment: So I know this is an old thread but just wanted to add comments for people like me who still end up visiting this thread.

SortedDictionary.Keys.ToList() is **O(n)** operation. Meaning it would gather all the keys and return them.

After getting the list of Key if we do a binary search then yes it would be **O(log n)** operation but we have already paid the upfront cost in getting all the keys.

Hence, unfortunately, this is not really equivalent of Treemap floorEntry or ceilingEntry